# Elasticsearch 6.4 in Docker Swarm: memory locking requested for elasticsearch process but memory is not locked

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, docker-swarm, elastic-stack

I am trying to run Elasticsearch in a Docker Swarm.
This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.2
    networks:
      - swarm_network
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1000M
```

I got this error:
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: memory locking requested for elasticsearch process but memory is not locked

Does anyone know why this error and how to solve it?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_memory_lock_check.html

Answer (score 2):

Set up `LimitMEMLOCK=infinity` to docker.service unit works fine for me (docker 18.06.1-ce running on ubuntu server 1804)

(credits: zzswang on https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-containers/issues/1)

```
echo -e "[Service]\nLimitMEMLOCK=infinity" | SYSTEMD_EDITOR=tee systemctl edit docker.service

systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set the ulimits correctly , But I think it is a privileged operation so you will need to docker run it as privileged.

https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk/issues/243

try this ( i am not sure please check the syntax)

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.2
    networks:
      - swarm_network
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1000M
```

Comment: It doesn't work neither. I have no idea how to solve the error. :(

Comment: remove the locking option

Comment: If I remove that one, it crashes as well. :(

Comment: dont remove it , but set it to false